# An error occured while installing flair and pytorch with pipenv in windows with Pycharm

Tags: python, pytorch, pipenv, pipfile, flair

I am having problems installing the python packages `flair` and `pytorch` via `pipenv` and have not been able to resolve this issue yet. Since I am trying to version my python git repository with `Pipfile + Pipfile.lock` instead of `requirements.txt` this is currently not possible:

`pipenv install flair`

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.1.0 (from flair->-r c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\temp\pipenv-plyx3uwp-requirements\pipenv-xh_afa_r-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.1.0 (from flair->-r c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\temp\pipenv-plyx3uwp-requirements\pipenv-xh_afa_r-requirement.txt (line 1)) Installation Failed`

I tried these variants of installing `torchvision`:

`pipenv install torchvision`

to install `torchvision` which should pick up the latest torch version

`pipenv install torch==1.3`

to install torch

`pipenv install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu92/torch-0.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

alternative way to install torch (here is more binaries:  https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#windows-binaries)

`pipenv install git+https://github.com/pytorch/vision#egg=torchvision`

Another alternative way,

```
Error text: Collecting torchvision
  Downloading torchvision-0.5.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.18.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (12.7 MB)
Collecting pillow>=4.1.1
  Downloading Pillow-7.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2.0 MB)
Collecting six
  Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
```

`pipenv install torchvision`

```
users\user.name\appdata\local\temp\pipenv-hf2be0xq-requirements\pipenv-57akhz4j-requirement.txt (line
1)) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.4.0 (from torchvision->-r c:\users\user.name\appdat
a\local\temp\pipenv-hf2be0xq-requirements\pipenv-57akhz4j-requirement.txt (line 1))
Installation Failed
```

---

The only way it was possible to install torchvision was without its dependent packages:

`pipenv run pip install --no-deps torchvision`

But this did not resolve the problem of installing flair via pipenv since the dependencies are needed.

Comment: Provide your Python version. The `torch` python package is not available in a lot of Python versions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have the following python version: python 3.7.5 64bit

Comment: Can you create a new environment and run `pipenv install torch==1.3.1`. What's the output?

Comment: same error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.3.1 (from -r c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\temp\pipenv-fg5mza4n-requirements\pipenv-_7xxn7ek-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions
: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.3.1 (from -r c:\users\user.name\appdata\local\temp\pipenv-fg5mza4n-requirements\pipenv-_7xxn7ek-requirement.txt (line 1))`

Answer (score 1):

Try to cleanup the Pipfile and the virtual environment first. It looks like the transitive dependencies and the ones declared in the Pipfile clash.

Then try to install torchvision like this:

```
pipenv install torchvision
```

This will install the latest torchvision version and the compatible torch version:

[Source](https://github.com/pytorch/vision):

```
torch   torchvision     python
master / nightly    master / nightly    >=3.6
1.5.0   0.6.0   >=3.5
1.4.0   0.5.0   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.8
1.3.1   0.4.2   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.7
1.3.0   0.4.1   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.7
1.2.0   0.4.0   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.7
1.1.0   0.3.0   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.7
<=1.0.1     0.2.2   ==2.7, >=3.5, <=3.7
```

Flair works with Pytorch 1.1+ as stated [here](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair):

> The project is based on PyTorch 1.1+ and Python 3.6+, because method
> signatures and type hints are beautiful.

After installing torchvision proceed to install flair:

```
pipenv install flair
```

Here you can find a working Pipfile and Pipfile.lock file, after the two operations were concluded:

Pipfile

```
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
torchvision = "*" 
flair = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

[Pipfile.lock](https://git.io/JJvQo)